# How can these UI layout/style can be labeled and differentiated from a stylistic standpoint?

Tags: gui-design, layout

It is often difficult for a non specialist to label or to describe some UI layouts.. Is there a glossary or a source that can help meeting the right language to talk about an interface general look ?

I have three particular examples in mind:

Example 1 is : [image]

Example 2 is [image]

This design looks much simpler, nearly like a toy.. compared to the previous one, it better fits the need of users who are not into computer tools.

Example 3 relates to onboard computers [image]
Onboard computers are such that clicking on a list option displays the state corresponding to this option. This is highly menu-driven as once an option (or meny entry) is chosen, the user goes deeper in the arborescence and must return back to access higher level options.

Is there a good source for knowing how designers would label, describe, and differentiate such UI layouts (and more that exist)?

Thanking you in advance for your feedback

Answer (score 1):

Several books deal with labeling of different layouts and patterns. Somehow I never seem to come across them in my work though. I think people aren't that aware and that the glossary would go over most peoples heads; like, you can only make yourself understood with this lingo in your internal work, not in connection with other proficiencies.

[Here is a link to some examples](http://designingwebinterfaces.com/designing-web-interfaces-12-screen-patterns) from the immortal *Designing Web Interfaces*.

It's not that easy to find perfect matches between the examples from the link and your examples, but this is how I would map it:

1) I would say we might have a case Parallel Panels here - *This pattern is ideal for organizing chunks of information that are similar or have interdependent tendencies.* But it also has a lot of Interactive Model in it - *characterized by many interactive elements associated with the key object (a calendar, map, graph, chart, canvas).*

2) Well, looks a bit like a spreadsheet, but Interactive Model has calendar as an application in its description so It might be another case of that pattern here.

3)  Wow... I don't see this one in any of the examples. I would maybe call it "Navigation based layout".

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found this source about "website navigation structures" that says the last example looks like it involves hierarchichal navigation http://www.etc.edu.cn/eet/Articles/wpdnav/index.htm.

Comment: A stylistic difference between examples 1 and 2 is that the first one looks like a form and requires mouse/keyboard. The second rather looks like the UI that cashiers use, and is meant to type directly on a screen with fingers.